# ValueError: signal only works in main thread - Django - mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, signals, mod-wsgi

I am trying to execute a shell command and kill it using python **signal** module.

I know signals work only with main thread, so I run the Django development server with,

```
python manage.py runserver --nothreading --noreload
```

and it works fine.

But when i deploy the django application with Apache/mod_wsgi, it shows the following error:

```
[Fri Sep 12 20:07:00 2014] [error]     response = function.call(request, **data)
[Fri Sep 12 20:07:00 2014] [error]   File "/Site/cloud/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dajaxice/core/Dajaxice.py", line 18, in call
[Fri Sep 12 20:07:00 2014] [error]     return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Sep 12 20:07:00 2014] [error]   File "/Site/cloud/soc/website/ajax.py", line 83, in execute
[Fri Sep 12 20:07:00 2014] [error]     data = scilab_run(code, token, book_id, dependency_exists)
[Fri Sep 12 20:07:00 2014] [error]   File "/Site/cloud/soc/website/helpers.py", line 58, in scilab_run
[Fri Sep 12 20:07:00 2014] [error]     output = task.run().communicate()[0]
[Fri Sep 12 20:07:00 2014] [error]   File "/Site/cloud/soc/website/timeout.py", line 121, in run
[Fri Sep 12 20:07:00 2014] [error]     lambda sig,frame : os.killpg(self.pgid,self.timeoutSignal) )
[Fri Sep 12 20:07:00 2014] [error] ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

Here is my apache virtualhost setting:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess testcloud display-name=scilab_cloud  user=apache group=apache threads=1
WSGIProcessGroup testcloud
WSGIScriptAlias / /Site/cloud/soc/soc/wsgi.py
WSGIImportScript /Site/cloud/soc/soc/wsgi.py process-group=testcloud application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

I also have the below settings outside virtualhost in httpd.conf:

```
WSGIRestrictSignal Off
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```

[Here is the link](https://gist.github.com/devietti/1526975) to the program which uses **signal** and the one which I use in my django application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

are you running with DEBUG enabled in setting.py ?
If yes try disabling it to see if the issue persists.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: it wasn't rhetoric, op didn't specify. from django's documentation :  "It is also important to remember that when running with DEBUG turned on, Django will remember every SQL query it executes." so i think it might explain the problem.

Comment: You can decide. Either it is a rhetoric question in an answer, which is not really bad, I just recommend against it; or it is not an answer at all and you are asking a question which you want an answer to. In that case this is not an answer at all and can be flagged and deleted as such, because you should ask that kind of question in a comment. You do have the commenting privilege for that.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that can be done that easily, or at least not with mod_wsgi. The decision to thread or not to thread is the sum of build and run time options in both apache and mod_wsgi, which are both set by default, to threading.

I would point you to the docs about that, but I can only post two links, so I think it's better to spend them in proposing a solution:

I had decently good experiences running shell commands from python with [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/index.html), which even has an asynchronous execution module. Maybe you can start your python code running the shell command, and deal with the callback object when needed.

Or, even better, as `sh` asks you to have some cares when handling signals, you could just run it without the asynchronous execution module, but in another process with [multiprocessing.Proces](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process), which will give you a `Process` object you can just kill with `object.terminate()`